# What happens if you leave an unpaid utilities bill in an EEA country you no longer live in?

Tags: relocation, legal, europe, portugal, utilities

If a person from an EEA country, for example Denmark, moves to another EEA country for example Portugal, and then moves out of 'Portugal' leaving behind an unpaid power bill, will this unpaid bill be likely to cause any problems for that person in the future assuming that they never revisit Portugal again, but will visit and live in other EEA countries, including of course Denmark?

Comment: Did you have a landlord?

Comment: @Zich yeah, of course.

Comment: I guess (s)he has to pay on your behalf! Are you doing this intentionally? I mean, are you able to pay the bill but you simply don’t want to!?

Comment: @Zich bill is in my name, not theirs. And it sorta just happened; I'm not able to easily pay the bill since I already left.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The utility company might do one or more  of several things, depending on the size of the debt:

- Write off the debt
- Chase you for the money
- Pass the debt to a debt collection agency
- Obtain a court judgement in your absence
- Something else

Whatever they elect to do, they will note your default on their records, and notify any credit reference agencies they deal with. Since credit reference agencies operate internationally this could well come back to bite you from unexpected directions.

You say you're in Europe. There are many ways to transfer money around Europe cheaply, easily and quickly. Do the right thing and pay the bill.